# How to import js files on Maya or 3ds max?

Tags: javascript, three.js, maya, 3dsmax

I am trying to open a js file on Maya (2013) and 3ds max (2016), but there aren't three.js importers for these softwares. How can I import a js file properly on Maya or 3ds max? Is there any other software I can use to open a js file? This js file comes with morph targets, so I would like to import these morph targets as well. I tried to import using Blender, but there was nothing in the scene.

Comment: Have you tried converting with the [Three.js editor](http://threejs.org/editor/)?

Comment: I tried to use Three.js editor, but it did not export the morph targets, only the mesh.

Comment: you could check how the morph targets are in the JSON and extract them to separate meshes, with just copy-paste or writing a (e.g. python) script to do that .. they are similar to mesh objects anyway, for example to create them for three.js from obj files you simply have a file per morph.

Comment: I did not understand how to do that exactly. Does each file per morph come with only the morph information (name and vertices)? Do I have to import each file per morph into the scene and the mesh as obj files?

Comment: Yes. I was assuming that you can then combine the separate meshes to morphtargets in Max or Maya. For example in this example file, you can see how the basic geom is in the verts array on line 21. Then the morphs are starting from line 24. So if you make a copy of the file, remove the morphs, and put verts from a morph to be the basic geom, you can import it to the editor and export as obj. And repeat the same for all morphs. Either manually or by programming. Also, formats like OBJ are simple so is possible to just program the whole thing and not use the editor, like bjorke suggested.

Comment: Oops forgot the link and it didn't fit anyhow: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/models/animated/horse.js

Comment: When I try to do what you suggested, there is an error: 'SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string' on Three.js editor.

Comment: It worked! I did what you suggested and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry to disappoint you but there is no direct way to import a THREE.js scene into Max or Maya, since THREE.js doesn't output geometry -- just pictures. You might consider writing OBJ as a text stream from THREE.js, and saving to disk or writing to console , and doing the same for each morph target, but this is no small undertaking, and might not really get you to what you want anyway. Are you sure that the THREE.js scene that you are considering doesn't already have external resources in some format like OBJ or COLLADA, which you could just fetch from the appropriate server (or even in teh directory of your own project)?

Comment: downvoted as seems misleading:

three.js does support saving as JSON, and the editor indeed seems to support both importing that JSON and exporting as OBJ and other formats, as hinted in 2pha's comment above. i'm surprised if morph targets would survive that process though but anyhow that approach might get him started ok.

Comment: This is only true for the very simplest tinkertoy three.js scenes. For most any real applications, direct conversion is probably impractical, since three.js, as an integration of 3d iamging and web data, is intrinsically changeable and dynamic, unlike typical Maya or Max scenes. In fact the OP has already said that such expart as you descibe is a fail.    Exporting a THREE.js scene to Maya is a problem rather like experting a javascript program to an Excel spreadsheet. Possible in some very narrow cases, but: only in those very narrow cases. And this is not one of them, apparently.

Comment: Yes after thinking this more I actually tried to remove the downvote yesterday already but that doesn't seem to be possible (only if you edit the answer :). It's just for the "doesn't output geometry -- just pictures", which is not really true with all the JSON serialization code in three.js objects. People seem to improve those often so it seems they do use three.js to create scenes that then save for other purposes. Or with the editor just for later editing. Anyhow your advice to write a morph target export or to search for the original files is good.